# Outlook Event Edit and save option click- event handler to trigger in my add-ins

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In outlook event Edit - save option click ,i want to trigger this event in my outlook add-ins , any specific event handler is available for this save option click

I want this trigger for edited event data for updating this in salesforce , so i want this trigger on click the save button

In this case attendee and date and time  edit triggers available but , In this some case user after the edit may be discard the edit ,so i am unable to use this event handlers

I want this trigger on save button click

Any thoughts about this please share

Note : My outlook add-ins developed using javascript language

Thanks in Advance

[Attached screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70OYd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no UI-less function or event for that. Event based activation is described in the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) article.

Comment: Any possible to add a custom button in event edit modal near to save and send buttton , i want to trigger some function in outlook add-ins by using onclick , i want this custom button in outlook add-ins , it show on the outlook event edit modal

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions in separate threads, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: Currently this feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions